# Retrieve text from span using xpath or css query

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I need to retrieve text from the following span element without splitting it into text sections.

```html
<span class="a-size-base review-text">I purchased this from Fry's Electronics.
<br/>
<br/>
The picture is quite good after tweaking the settings.  An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion.  Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text.  I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image.  I'm very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing.
<br/>
<br/>
I wasn't planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed.  The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow.  The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files.  I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails.  When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good.  If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems.
<br/>
<br/>
The unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze.  You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you're ready to go.  The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter.  The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome.
<br/>
<br/>
The stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide.  The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached.  The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge.
<br/>
<br/>
Overall I'm very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range.  (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry's).
<br/>
<br/>
NOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it's likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing.  Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.
</span>
```

However on applying my xpath query

> //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "review-text", " " ))]/text()

I get this:

```html
Text='I purchased this from Fry's Electronics.'
Text=''
Text='The picture is quite good after tweaking the settings.  An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion.  Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text.  I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image.  I'm very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing.'
Text=''
Text='I wasn't planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed.  The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow.  The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files.  I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails.  When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good.  If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems.'
Text=''
Text='The unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze.  You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you're ready to go.  The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter.  The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome.'
Text=''
Text='The stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide.  The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached.  The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge.'
Text=''
Text='Overall I'm very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range.  (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry's).'
Text=''
Text='NOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it's likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing.  Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.'
```

I would like to retrieve one block of text without the breakages.
I am using this xpath tester [http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handy feature of scrapy Selectors is selector chaining, so you can start with CSS selection and then apply XPath string methods, such as [`string()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) or [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space).

Here's an example scrapy 1.1 shell session:

```
~$ scrapy shell
2016-08-16 12:20:57 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-08-16 12:20:57 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'}
(...)
In [1]: html = '''<span class="a-size-base review-text">I purchased this from Fry's Electronics.
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: The picture is quite good after tweaking the settings.  An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion.  Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text.  I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image.  I'm very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing.
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: I wasn't planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed.  The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow.  The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files.  I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails.  When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good.  If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems.
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: The unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze.  You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you're ready to go.  The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter.  The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome.
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: The stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide.  The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached.  The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge.
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: Overall I'm very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range.  (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry's).
   ...: <br/>
   ...: <br/>
   ...: NOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it's likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing.  Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.
   ...: </span>'''

In [2]: import scrapy

In [3]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text=html)

In [4]: selector.css('span.review-text').xpath('string()').extract_first()
Out[4]: 'I purchased this from Fry\'s Electronics.\n\n\nThe picture is quite good after tweaking the settings.  An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion.  Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text.  I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image.  I\'m very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing.\n\n\nI wasn\'t planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed.  The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow.  The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files.  I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails.  When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good.  If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems.\n\n\nThe unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze.  You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you\'re ready to go.  The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter.  The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome.\n\n\nThe stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide.  The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached.  The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge.\n\n\nOverall I\'m very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range.  (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry\'s).\n\n\nNOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it\'s likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing.  Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.\n'

In [5]: print(selector.css('span.review-text').xpath('string()').extract_first())
I purchased this from Fry's Electronics.


The picture is quite good after tweaking the settings.  An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion.  Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text.  I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image.  I'm very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing.


I wasn't planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed.  The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow.  The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files.  I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails.  When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good.  If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems.


The unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze.  You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you're ready to go.  The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter.  The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome.


The stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide.  The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached.  The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge.


Overall I'm very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range.  (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry's).


NOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it's likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing.  Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.


In [6]: print(selector.css('span.review-text').xpath('normalize-space()').extract_first())
I purchased this from Fry's Electronics. The picture is quite good after tweaking the settings. An HDMI feed from my PC results in very clear text with no distortion. Be sure to turn down the sharpness to avoid artifacts around text. I think this screen may offer 4:4:4 chroma subsampling based on the attached test image. I'm very pleased with the viewing angles and the screen is definitely usable for more than just straight ahead viewing. I wasn't planning on using the Smart features, but the Netflix app works really well and is responsive enough to not become annoyed. The wifi streaming playback is very smooth, but navigating the folder structure is horribly slow. The interface insists on creating thumbnails for each movie file, which takes forever if you have a directory with many files. I would much rather just see a detailed list without thumbnails. When you finally do find your desired movie the playback is very good. If you keep the directory contents small (~10 items or fewer) you may not have any problems. The unit is very thin and light and setup was a breeze. You just have to put in 4 screws to attach the base and then you're ready to go. The power adapter comes with a "brick" style converter. The remote is well laid out and the menus are easy to navigate without feeling cumbersome. The stand is 8" deep x 22.25" wide. The TV stands 26.5" from table top to the top of the bezel with stand attached. The TV is 42.75" wide from outside bezel edge to outside bezel edge. Overall I'm very pleased with what this offers in the $400-500 range. (I actually paid $398 but that was after some customer service adjustments at Fry's). NOTE: If you see any strange distortion in the images it's likely a result of the camera, image compression, and resizing. Some of the strange patterns seen in the images are not present when viewing in person.
```

Comment: Thank you @paul trmbrth. Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the entire `<span>` element to `string` :

```
string(
  //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " a-size-base review-text" ), concat( " ", "review-text", " " ))]
)
```

Notice that this only works for the first `<span>` element matching the criteria. In XPath 2.0, you can use [`string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) which will work with arbitrary number of `<span>` elements :

```
string-join(   
    //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " a-size-base review-text" ), concat( " ", "review-text", " " ))]/text(),
    ""
)
```

Comment: I am using **lxml** that only supports _xpath 1.0_ so I cannot use `string-join`. If I convert the entire element to `string`. The _xpath_ query seems to return one string instead of a list.

Comment: The following returns a list on scrapy shell. `response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "review-text", " " ))]').extract()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to post process to remove html tags using python regex.

```
re.sub( r'<span class="a-size-base review-text">|<br>|</span>', "", text)
```

I tried @har07 suggestions however;

- scrapy uses lxml that only supports *xpath 1.0* hence I could not take advantage of `string-join` which is available in *xpath 2.0*
- I could not get a list of selectors from my xpath query when I tried `string`.